# TypeError: coolArr.printArray is not a function when importing npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, babeljs, es6-class

I created a package with an index.js that looks like this:

```
module.exports = class CoolArray extends Array {
  printArray() {
    console.log(this);
  }
}
```

I then use babel to transpile the code using es2015 syntax.

After linking my package to my test folder I can import and use my class just fine like this:

```
import CoolArray from 'package-name';

const coolArr = new CoolArray(1, 2, 3);
```

However, I can't use any of the classes functions on the `coolArr` object.

`coolArr.printArray()` gives me the error `TypeError: coolArr.printArray is not a function`. What am I doing wrong?

---

Ok I've found a solution. My index.js file now looks like this:

```
module.exports = class AsyncArray extends Array {
  constructor(...elements) {
    super(...elements);

    this.printArray = () => {
      console.log(this);
    }
  }
}
```

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72165237/18069264) should follow you to the full answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
class CoolArray extends Array {
  printArray() {
    console.log(this);
  }
}

module.exports = {
    CoolArray,
};
```

Then it can be used like this:

```
import { CoolArray } from 'package-name';

const coolArr = new CoolArray(1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: Tried that but I'm getting the same issue. `const coolArr = new CoolArray(1, 2, 3)` works. For example `console.log(coolArr)` prints the array, but `coolArr.printArray()` still throws an error

Answer (score 0):

Refactoring my index.js file to look like this allows me to use the class functions without any error:

```
module.exports = class AsyncArray extends Array {
  constructor(...elements) {
    super(...elements);

    this.printArray = () => {
      console.log(this);
    }
  }
}
```